# Need help extracting image src url from a pinterest rss feed

Tags: rss, expressionengine, pinterest, magpie

Basically I am trying to add a Pinterest feed widget to an ExpressionEngine site.  I found [this tutorial](http://www.emtwowebstudios.com/play/adding_your_pinterest_feed_to_expressionengine/) which was very helpful but the issue is that I can't use the Tag Stripping plugin that is referenced because the site I am helping out with uses ExpressionEngine 1x and the plugin is only for 2x.

If you look at the source of a Pinterest rss feed like: http://pinterest.com/amazon/feed.rss you will see that within the `<description>` tags is the url for the Pinterest image along with the pin's title, tags and a relative link to the pin on pinterest.  I'd like to be able to extract only the value between the double quotes after 'img src'.

The tutorial also uses a plugin called Magpie which is already loaded on the site so I am good there.

Ideally, I'd like my code to look something like this:

```
{exp:magpie url="http://pinterest.com/amazon/feed.rss" parse="inward"
refresh="720" limit="5"} {items}<a href="{link}" target="_blank"><img
src="<?php code-to-grab-the-img-src->{description} ?>"
alt="{title}"></a>{/items} {/exp:magpie}
```

Obviously "code-to-grab-the-img-src->{description}" doesn't work so I am looking for a function or something that will. How can I tell Magpie to extract only the img src value without using the SuperGeekery Tag Stripper plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest building a simple plugin to handle this, you could use the same regex as [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044282/174299) (which is failing due to trouble getting the `{description}` content into PHP).

Here's what your plugin could look like:

```
<?php

$plugin_info = array(
  'pi_name' => 'Get Pinterest Image',
  'pi_version' => '1.0',
  'pi_author' => 'Derek Hogue',
  'pi_author_url' => 'http://amphibian.info',
  'pi_description' => 'Grabs the image URL from a Pinterest RSS feed description element.',
  'pi_usage' => Get_pinterest_image::usage()
  );

class Get_pinterest_image
{

var $return_data = "";

  function Get_pinterest_image()
  {
    global $TMPL;
    $fallback = $TMPL->fetch_param('fallback_image');
    preg_match("/src=\"(.+)(?=\"&gt;&lt;\/a&gt;)/ui", $TMPL->tagdata, $matches);
    $this->return_data = (!empty($matches)) ? $matches[1] : $fallback;
  }

  function usage()
  {
  ob_start(); 
  ?>
    {exp:get_pinterest_image fallback="/path/to/fallback_image.png"}{description}{/exp:get_pinterest_image}

    Where {description} is the "description" XML node from the Pinterest RSS feed (likely parsed via the Magpie plugin).
  <?php
  $buffer = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean(); 
  return $buffer;
  }  

}

?>
```

This would, as per EE conventions, be named **get_pinterest_image.php**, and go into your **/plugins/** folder. Then in your template:

```
{exp:magpie url="http://pinterest.com/amazon/feed.rss" refresh="720" limit="5" parse="inward"}
    {items}
        <a href="{link}" target="_blank"><img src="{exp:get_pinterest_image fallback="/path/to/fallback_image.png"}{description}{/exp:get_pinterest_image}" alt="{title}" /></a>
    {/items}
{/exp:magpie}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but as you can probably tell I am just learning a lot of this.  Where exactly in the plugin file do I paste in the regex?  I tried a few different spots but am having trouble getting the plugin manager in EE to not blow up when I refresh to see if I can see the my newly created plugin.  Can you let me know what area exactly this should go in?  You have been so helpful, thanks.

Comment: to be more clear when I refresh the plugin manager after I ftp my plugin into the /sys/plugins/ directory I get "No direct script access allowed"

Comment: Eureka!!! With a couple modifications.  I had to ad "pi." to the plugin file for it to be recognized by my plugin manager so pi.get_pinterest_image.php.  I also edited your regex to
 '/src="([^"]+)"/' which I stole from this Wordpress Pinterest widget:http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/mg-pinterest-strips-widget/trunk/mg-pinterest-strips.php.  Thank you soo much!!

Answer (score 0):

Sure - enable PHP on output, then use this regex:

```
{exp:magpie url="http://pinterest.com/amazon/feed.rss" refresh="720" limit="5"}
{items}
<?php
    preg_match("/src=\"(.+)(?=\"&gt;&lt;\/a&gt;)/ui", '{description}', $matches);
    $src = (!empty($matches)) ? $matches[1] : '/path/to/default-image.png';
?>
    <a href="{link}" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" alt="{title}"></a>
{/items}
{/exp:magpie}
```

This code includes a fallback for another image to use in case the image `src` can't be found for some reason.

Not tested, but it should work.

Comment: Hmm, I get 5 broken image boxes because the img src is your fallback of /path/to/default-image.png which doesn't exist (yet).  The link and alt tag work correctly.  Any guesses as to why?  Thanks so much!  I need to learn about rexeg.

Comment: Sorry, the pattern wasn't specific enough. Try the updated code?

Comment: Nope, still giving me the default image path.  I ran your regular expression and the value of one <description> tag on this tester: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php and the result was an empty array.  Thanks so much for helping me with this.

Comment: Ack, sorry, forgot to escape a forward slash. Try one more time!

Comment: Still no luck.  I think it is having trouble actually pulling the input string out of {description}.  I've tried using very simple regular expressions to populate src="" with anything to no avail.  Could it be a limitation of Magpie that you can't use regex within it to drill down to a specific part of an XML object?

Comment: Do you have PHP enabled on output?

Comment: I have 'Yes' ticked for 'Allow PHP'.  There is other PHP used within this template that I am trying your code on.  'PHP Parsing Stage' is set for 'Input' not 'Output' but I checked all other templates on the site and say input there.

Comment: Yeah, getting the description into that PHP expression is the issue, and it has to do with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

RSS parsing is hard!  If you're willing to go a little more complicated and bring the feed content into EE, I've had good luck with the EE2-only DataGrab, so you might find some happiness with the free EE1 predecessor: [FeedGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/feedgrab).